# Explanation of code sorting array into object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
a = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (!result[a[i]])
        result[a[i]] = 0;
    ++result[a[i]];
}
```

Can someone please explain this code snippet? I'm not sure what the `++result[a[i]]` and the conditional mean. Either this is creative logic or high level JS that I don't know.

Comment: That code alone wont sort an array

Comment: It's not *sorting* the array, it's computing the frequency distribution of the array's elements. @derp said it well enough, I think.

Answer (score 2):

it's a count of how many times a number appears in the array

the `!result[a[i]]` checks whether or not we have seen that number before and if not, we set the count to be 0. We then increment that count using `++result[a[i]];`

Here's a fiddle below
https://jsfiddle.net/erth1qq2/

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple code.It counts the repitition of elements inside the array.

**In the first iteration**

**result[a[i]]** is **result[5]** which is currently **null** so the if condition **if(!result[a[i]])** is satisfied so the value of result[5] is assigned 0 and increased by result[a[i]]++ to become 1.

**In the second iteration**
**result[a[i]]** is **result[5]** which is currently 1 so the if condition **if(!result[a[i]])** is  not satisfied so the value of result[5] is increased by 1 and becomes 2

In this way the repetition of each element is stored into results with the element itself as key

Hope you understood

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`!result[a[i]]` is checking object key existed !

- If exist , it will pass assign 0 to its value and increasing its value to 1.
- If not exist ,it will assign 0 to its value and increasing its value to 1.

  ```
  a      = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
  result = { };
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  if(!result[a[i]])  //check object key is exist 
      result[a[i]] = 0;
  ++result[a[i]];
  }
  ```